# Custom logger using SLF4J which logs messages in specific message formats

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

I have a requirement to log messages in specific message format like: 
messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},response={}"
messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},request={}"
so that we can create dashboards using splunk.Iam using logback to achieve it. So I created custom logger which implements SLF4J logger as below:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public  class MyLogger implements Logger {      
private  static Logger log;

public MyLogger(Class<?> name){
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
}

/**
 * used to log request in the methods at debug level with messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},request={}"
 * @param methodSignature
 * @param request
 */
public void logDebugRequest(String methodSignature,String request){
    String messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},request={}";
    debug(messageFormat,"applicationname",methodSignature,request);
}

/**
 * used to log response from methods at debug level with messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},response={}"
 * @param methodSignature
 * @param response
 */
public void logDebugResponse(String methodSignature,Object response){
    String messageFormat = "applicationName={},methodSignature={},response={}";
    debug(messageFormat,"applicationname",methodSignature,response);
}
@Override
public void debug(String arg0, Object... arg1) {
    log.debug(arg0, arg1);

}

@Override
public void error(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
    log.error(arg0,arg1);

}
..//other overridden methods from slf4j

}
```

In my project, I used logging aspect class to log request and response of methods as below:

```
public  class CommonLoggingAspect {
private final MyLogger log = new MyLogger(CommonLoggingAspect.class);
// this advice runs around the method execution and is used to log the request, response of methods
@Around("within(com.product.rest.productresource)")
protected Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    StringBuilder methodSignature = new StringBuilder();
    methodSignature.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()).append(".").append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()).append("()");
    log.logDebugRequest(methodSignature.toString(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

    try {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        log.logDebugResponse(methodSignature.toString(), result);

        return result;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.logError(methodSignature.toString(), e.getClass().getName(), "Illegal arguments " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        throw e;
    }    
} }
```

In the  Productresource class methods I have logged some messages as well example:-

```
Public class ProductResource{
MyLogger log = new MyLogger(ProductResource.class);
public String method1(string req1){
int x=0;
log.debug("value of x is " + x);
return "ss";
}

public String method2(string req2){
int y=0;
log.debug("value of y is " + y);
return "yy";
}
```

}

```
In the log file I can see the msgs printed as :
class name                            message
com.product.CommonLoggingAspect -     applicationName=product,methodSignature=ProductResource.method1,request="req1"
com.product.CommonLoggingAspect - value of x is  0 //this message is logged     in ProductResource class, but the class name is printed as CommonLoggingAspect
com.product.CommonLoggingAspect -    applicationName=product,methodSignature=ProductResource.method1,response=ss
```

So my question is : Is there any way by which I can achieve logging in specific message formats. In my current approach I used custom logger which implements slf4j logger and in my classes, iam creating a new instance of MyLogger as below:

```
 MyLogger log = new MyLogger(ProductResource.class);
```

which doesn't seem right to me, as I didnt write my own LoggerFactory class.
As a result Iam creating multiple instances of logger and running in to issues like printing of incorrect class names in the log and also ran in to lock issues.
Iam looking for an example of  LoggerFactory and StaticLoggerBinder class.Can you please give any suggestions.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @vesan: I just finished editing my question, can you please look in to it.

Comment: @vesan: I want to log messages in specific message formats, I dont want to explicitly call slf4j debug(messageFormat,"applicationname",methodSignature,response) method, so i wrote custom logger which implements slf4j logger, but i didnt implement loggerfactory and staticbinder class, due to which iam creating multiple instances of MyLogger and ended up printing wrong class name. can you please provide me the example of loggerfactory, staticbinder class ,for my custom logger  or is there any other approach to achieve logging in specific message formats

Comment: @ChandanaReddy The source for [SLF4J is available on GitHub](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j), the slf4j simple binding can be used as an example.

Comment: Hi @ChandanaReddy, sorry I don't know anything about this framework. I just wanted to let you know that it's unclear what you're asking. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: I don't think you need to write a custom logger, that's an overkill. You can easily extend some existing logger, like logback or log4j2. Look into writing custom PatternLayout. I'll try to give you an example a little later

Comment: @traylz:Thanks for the response. I will look in to the option of extending logback logger. Can you please provide your example when you get a chance.

Comment: @traylz: logback logger is a final class, it can't be extended. We are using logback for our logging. I think the only way is to implement slf4j logger , and i need to create LoggerFactory , StaticLoggerBinder classes, but i don't have clarity on LoggerFactory class creation.